# Choosing a Websocket REST Paradigm

Tags: rest, websocket, socket.io, signalr, webhooks

Since REST is an architectural style, not a protocol, it can be applied to most any protocol form - such as websockets.  That's exactly what I'd like to do, but I'd like help deciding on an approach.

As I do my research, I'm finding that there are three paradigms I could follow:

- **Simulated Request-Response**.  This is what is implemented in the [SwaggerSocket library](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-socket/wiki/SwaggerSocket-Protocol).  Each client request has an ID.  Each server-push response has the same ID, to allow correlation of request-response.
- **Notification-Only**.  The server pushes a resource address, implying that the client should perform a GET on that resource to discover what has changed.
- **Event Driven**.  The server-push is designed to look like an HTTP POST, perhaps similar to a webhook request.

I'd like to hear from those who have experience walking these paths, about which they found to be the most effective, and which tools they applied (such as SwaggerSocket mentioned above).

A major concern I have is simplified demuxing and de-serialization.  For example, suppose I have a client written in Typescript. I might like to deserialize server-push payload into a declared, *typed* object.  I think the consequences for each paradigm are as follows:

- **Simulated Request-Response** (SRR).  The SwaggerSocket message must be de-serialized twice.  First to discover the response ID and/or "path", and second to retrieve the actual payload into a "typed" object.  A little clumsy, but doable.
- **Notification-Only**.  The server-push message can be deserialized into a single pre-defined type, since it contains little more than a REST resource path.
- **Event Driven**.  If the "event" has no payload, then this is basically the same thing as the Notification-Only approach.  But if there is a payload, then once again a two-step deserialization would likely be necessary.

Other thoughts I have: The SRR might be the most limiting of the three, because every server-push theoretically is instigated by a client request.  The other two paradigms don't have that implicit model.  The Event Driven approach has the conceptual advantage of being similar-ish to a webhook callback.

To illustrate the Event Driven / webhook idea, I'll give a [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) example.

```
//client side.
hubProxy.On<HttpRequest>("EventNotice", request => {
    //Take apart the HttpResponse and dispatch through
    //my own routing mechanism...to handlers that 
    //further deserialize the inner payload.
});

//The corresponding server-push would of course be:
_context.Clients.All.EventNotice(myHttpRequest);
```

The above example is very achievable.  In fact, I would not be surprised somebody has example code (please share!) or even a supporting library for this purpose.

Again, of these different paradigms, which would you advise?  What supporting tools would you suggest?